# How to get the name of a variable

Tags: python, function, class

I'm practicing writing classes in Python and I'm stumped on how to do something.

```
class GolfClub:
    def __init__(self, size, distance):
        self.size = size
        self.distance = distance

    def hits_further(self, other):
        if self.distance > other.distance:
            return "(name of club variable) hits further"
        else:
            return "(name of club variable) hits further"
```

If I do:

```
club1 = GolfClub(5, 200)
club2 = GolfClub(6, 300)

club1.hits_further(club2)
```

How can I make the hits_further method return the name of the variable? For example, I would like it to return:

```
"club2 hits further"
```

How can I get the variable names into the method?

Comment: Assign a variable to the hits_further... Aka `club1_further =club1.hits_further(club2)` then `print(club1_further)`

Comment: `x = club2` — now two names refer to the same object.  Which name would you want?  If your objects need names, give them a name attribute.

Comment: whooha! you need to get to a runtime library. Not sure if it exists.

Comment: It is generally not possible to get one of the names of an object unless you pass it to the creation of the object...

Comment: You're right Steve, that would be the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traditionally, you'd give the instance a name:

```
class GolfClub:
    def __init__(self, name, size, distance):
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.distance = distance

    def hits_further(self, other):
        if self.distance > other.distance:
            return "%s hits further" % self.name
        else:
            return "%s hits further" % other.name

club1 = GolfClub('Driver', 5, 200)
club2 = GolfClub('9Iron', 6, 300)
club1.hits_further(club2)
```

The instance itself has no possible way of knowing what name you've given to the variable containing it. So, store the name inside the instance.

Comment: in fact it is possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, you can't do what you want here, because, in Python, the name is not a property of the variable. It's just a handle, which can be attached and reattached, while the object can have multiple names pointing to it, none of which is *the* name.

This is why others have suggested adding a name as an init parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If I were to do what you were doing, I would change your class to do something like:

```
class GolfClub:
    def __init__(self, size, distance):
        self.size = size
        self.distance = distance

    def hits_further(self, other):
        if self.distance > other.distance:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

And the code to do something like:

```
club1 = GolfClub(5, 200)
club2 = GolfClub(6, 300)

if club1.hits_further(club2):
    print("club1 hits further")
else:
    print("club2 hits further")
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to be able to print out the name of the variable.  Your code is only restricted to two possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Change the return statement to a `print` statement.

Add a `name` attribute to your class. Then do something like this:

```
class GolfClub:
    def __init__(self, size, distance,name):
        self.size = size
        self.name = name
        self.distance = distance

    def hits_further(self, other):
        if self.distance > other.distance:
            print self.name, "club hits further"
        else:
            print other.name ,"That club hits further"

club1 = GolfClub(5, 200,"c1")
club2 = GolfClub(6, 300,"c2")

club1.hits_further(club2)
```

As far as i know, what you wish to achieve is not really possible

Comment: This is really the only way I can see this being done without a runtime library as lalborno suggested

Comment: @rayryeng This still doesn't get you the name of the variable used as you suggest in the comment on my answer. While it is A method of doing it you can bind the class instance to any name which would still be different that that name passed in.

Answer (score 2):

In fact it can be done asking the stack

```
import inspect
import traceback
import sys
import re

class GolfClub:
    def __init__(self, size, distance):
        self.size = size
        self.distance = distance

    def hits_further(self, other):
        call_str= traceback.extract_stack()[0][3]
        m = re.search('([\w]+)\.hits_further\((.*)\)',call_str)

        self_name=m.group(1)
        other_name=m.group(2)
        if self.distance > other.distance:
            return self_name+" hits further"
        else:
            return other_name+" hits further"

club1=GolfClub(1,1)
club2=GolfClub(2,2)
print club1.hits_further(club2)
print club2.hits_further(club1)
```

The result is:

```
club2 hits further
club2 hits further
```

As asked by geogeogeo

Comment: This might work with your contrived example, but doesn't work if the variables are further away on the stack, and definitely doesn't produce the right output based on the comparison of distance. While you've tried to answer the exact question posed by the OP, the rest of us have given the answer to the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Obviously my solution is not recommendable. My solution is just an illustration of what it can be done if you really want to go in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this:

```
def name(**variable):
    return [x for x in variable]
```